# Swipebox iframe to fullscreen

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Hi there I have a basic swipebox light installed within an iframe.
When I click the zoom in is done inside the iframe and not in the main frame.

How can I set this right?

I've searched here but the template is different.

Here the iframe link: http://www.gattoragdoll.it/prova2/home/mamme-e-papa/papa.php
Here main frame: http://www.gattoragdoll.it/prova2/home/mamme-e-papa/

Here is the code I have installed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swipebox-master/lib/ios-orientationchange-fix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swipebox-master/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swipebox-master/src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> ;( function( $ ) {
$( '.gallery' ).swipebox(); 
} )( jQuery );
</script>
```

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: I tried but i can't make it work in the example...I can give the link to the direct page

Comment: That's fine, there are circumstances such as yours, which it might be infeasible to replicate the issue exactly. In your case, you could start out by just the iframe and maybe a stripped down version of the page in HTML. A link to the page is OK, but people tend to avoid them because it's risky going blindly into an unknown location.

Comment: Thanks...I've added the links to the main post ;) :)